# r - remove first row of condition per subject in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a long format dataframe with multiple subjects and multiple conditions for each subject.
I want to remove the first row of each condition (except the first one) for all subjects.
My dataframe looks like this:

```
> df <- data.frame(subj = c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4), rep(3,4)), cond = (rep(c("A", "A", "B", "B"),times=3)), value = round(runif(12, min = 0, max = 10)))
> df
subj cond value
1    A     1
1    A     5
1    B     3
1    B    10
2    A     6
2    A     5
2    B     2
2    B     0
3    A     5
3    A     8
3    B     5
3    B     2
```

I have found the duplicated() function but it only removes the first row of each condition for the first subject:

```
df <- df[duplicated(df$cond),]
subj cond value
 1    A     5
 1    B    10
 2    A     6
 2    A     5
 2    B     2
 2    B     0
 3    A     5
 3    A     8
 3    B     5
 3    B     2
```

Is there a way to "reset" the finding of a duplicate whenever a new subject begins?
And how can I stop it from excluding the first row of the first condition?

Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subset with the duplicated interaction of the two variables:

```
> df
   subj cond value
1     1    A     5
2     1    A     7
3     1    B     4
4     1    B     8
5     2    A     5
6     2    A     2
7     2    B     8
8     2    B     5
9     3    A     8
10    3    A     1
11    3    B     1
12    3    B     5

df1 <- df[!duplicated(interaction(df$subj, df$cond)),]

> df1
   subj cond value
1     1    A     5
3     1    B     4
5     2    A     5
7     2    B     8
9     3    A     8
11    3    B     1
```

---

Edit:

I've read your question again and it seems you want to remove the first row, not the last. In this case, use

```
df1 <- df[!duplicated(interaction(df$subj, df$cond), fromLast = TRUE),]

> df1
   subj cond value
2     1    A     4
4     1    B     9
6     2    A     9
8     2    B     7
10    3    A     1
12    3    B     2
```

Comment: Thank you, that works!
To keep all the rows of the first condition, I used the following indexing:
    df1 <- df[df$cond == "A" | !duplicated(interaction(df[df$cond != "B",]$subj, df[df$cond != "B",]$cond), fromLast = TRUE)]

Answer (score 0):

Alternative (but does depend on actual df):

```
df <- data.frame(subj = c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4), rep(3,4)), 
                 cond = (rep(c("A", "A", "B", "B"),times=3)), 
                 value = round(runif(12, min = 0, max = 10)))
df

dummy <- as.character(df$cond) # factor to character
mask <- c(FALSE, dummy[-1] == dummy[-length(dummy)])
df[mask,]
```